# Trying to add transparency opacity to background image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to darken images using transparency (opacity) so that the foreground text can be better read.

Here is my header HTML:

```css
.header-image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  /* image must be 1900 x 500 */
  background: url('back.1.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.headline {
  padding: 120px 0;
}

.headline h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: #24292E;
  background: rgba(36, 41, 46, 0.7);
  color: #FCFCFC;
}
```

```html
<header class="header-image" style="background: url(' URL TO IMAGE') center no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
  <div class="headline">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Headline</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

You will see that I added 'opacity: 1.0;' on the last line of 'header-image' but it didn't work.

Any idea where I am going wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't want to change transition of whole div, just an image I guess. You should place it using ::before pseudo-element. Now all css attributes will apply only to ::before:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<header class="header-image">
    <div class="headline">
     <div class="container">
      <h1>Headlines</h1>
     </div>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.header-image {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 180px;
}

.header-image:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/1500/1000');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 0;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.headline {
}

.headline h1 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 500;
    background: #24292E;
    background: rgba(36, 41, 46, 0.3);
    color: #FCFCFC;
    margin: 0;
}
```

https://jsbin.com/lisakez/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply opacity to a background image.

One way to get around this is to place the image you want as the background directly over the top of the container, which gives the impression it is set as the background. Then place any text directly over the top of the image by applying a higher z-index to the text.

```
.header-image {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

.header-image img {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; 
    top: 0; 
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; 
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.headline h1 { 
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 500;
    background: #24292E;
    background: rgba(36, 41, 46, 0.7);
    color: #FCFCFC; 
}

<header class="header-image"> 
    <div class="headline">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Headline</h1>
            <img src="your-image.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

[See fiddle](https://jsbin.com/nexiyikuxo/edit?html,css,output)